# Why does JSplitPane mash my GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout, jsplitpane

I don't really have example code for this (so I'll try to explain it), but I'm wondering if there is a way to stop `JSplitPane` from mashing my layouts?

I have two panels that I add into a `JSplitpane` which both have `GridBagLayout` on them. On the left pane I have a table. On the right pane I have a `JPanel` that displays information when the user interacts with the table. However, when the information is displayed on the right pane, the table gets mashed. (unable to display unless the divider is dragged all the way to the right).

I would think with a `GridBagLayout` that my table should still be visible no matter what. Even if it squished the columns and rows in.

I'm just wondering if this is a common problem, if so, is there a fix?

Comment: `GridBagLayout` is notorious for collapsing components when there is not the space required to display them.  OTOH for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks again for the quick response. I found the issue which indeed one would need the code to find it. I accidentally reset the GridBagLayout which killed all my previous constraints. This question can be closed/removed. :P thanks for fixing my grammar as well and giving me a chuckle

Comment: @AndrewThompson Will do, but it says I must wait two days to accept it :P

Comment: Fortunately I don't need to wait that long (very impatient) before I add - great question/answer.  +1.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was that when the table was clicked I reset the constraints to the JSplitPane. This caused the constraints to disappear and leave the GUI to do what is pleased.

Pseudo:

```
//set constraints for panel that contains table and random components
//if table clicked add data (with GridBagLayout) in other side of splitpane <-- this is where I accidentally reset the layout
```

So as soon as that line of code was removed, it functioned as expected.